# Add-On process to an android application

Tags: android

I developed a project with some features and I keep adding more features to my app.

Is any possible way to add-on my new features after some times as a add-on from internet?

Also I found this:

```
//Get the other apk's resources
Resources resources = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(
            "package.name.goes.here");
```

I don't know how it works, but I would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load some resources from different apk, you can look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) article about loading custom classes in dalvik VM. Maybe it helps.